# Kotlin - passing sortBy params as function parameter

Tags: function, sorting, kotlin, parameters, parameter-passing

Lets assume you have a class:

```
class Person{
  var age :Int? 
  var name :String? 
}
```

and then you have collection of this class, let's call it people :List.
You can call sort as:

```
people.sortBy{person -> person.age}
```

or

```
people.sortBy{person -> person.name}
```

Im wondering if its possible to write function definition that would sort by a given field? such as:

```
fun sortbyField(field:???){
  peple.sortBy{field}
}
```

I have no idea if its possible, if so, how to define "field" parameter.
Thanks!

Comment: This seems quite redundant, you can just pass a field reference to the `sortBy` method: `people.sortBy(Person::name)`.

Comment: Im actually needing it for a little bit more complex case then an example provided in a question therefore your solution won't work. Thanks for the input anyway!

Comment: Can you describe the case? It might be easier to come up with appropriate solution if we knew the constraints and requirements.

Comment: Sure! I have a list of items that are displayed horizontally. Let's say each object field has its own column. I want to find nice and simple way to sort this list after clicking on column header. Ideally, I would like to pass "header view" and "object field" to some method to handle clicks.

Comment: You may want to lay your eyes on [reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/member-references-and-reflection.html#obtaining-member-references-from-a-class-reference). Note however that reflection may negatively affect the performance, so use it cautiously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the function parameter accept a [function type with a receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types), like `Person.() -> T`, and then, inside the bodies of lambdas passed to the function, it will be possible to access a property of the implicit receiver:

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> sortUsing(fn: Person.() -> T) {
    people.sortBy { it.fn() }
}
```

<sub>Usages:</sub>

```
sortUsing { name }
sortUsing { age }
```

Alternatively, you can pass a [callable reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#callable-references) to the property as a functional argument, instead of a lambda:

```
people.sortBy(Person::name)
people.sortBy(Person::age)
```

This works for both functional parameters accepting a single argument, `(Person) -> T`, and for functional parameters with receiver, `Person.() -> T`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the field as a parameter if you do not call the function as a lambda expression:

```
people.sortedBy(Person::name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following is something you were looking for:

```
fun List<Person>.sortByHeader(header: String) = sortedWith(
    when (header) {
        "header_name" -> compareBy(nullsFirst(), Person::name)
        "header_age" -> compareBy(nullsLast(), Person::age)
        "header_time" -> compareBy(Person::time)
        else -> compareBy(Person::id)
    }
)
```

I used the following data class instead:

```
data class Person(val id: Int, val name: String?, val age : Int?, val time: LocalDateTime)
```

This way you can then call it using your header name, e.g.:

```
pepple.sortByHeader("header_id").run(::println)
pepple.sortByHeader("header_name").run(::println)
pepple.sortByHeader("header_time").run(::println)
pepple.sortByHeader("header_age").run(::println)
```

I just added some nullsFirst/nullsLast in case you want to have something like that in place as well.

If that is not what you were after, then using a function with receiver as [shown by hotkeys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805612/6202869) might be more appropriate for you. The next alternative is using reflection, but I will omit this one, as that should be used rather as a last resort.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another way to write it

```
people.sortBy { it.name }
```

In kotlin, when a lambda expect only one argument, you can simplify the syntax: `people.sort { it -> it.name }` becomes `people.sort { it.name }`. You have to use the name `it` though